# populate parameter with chars from text field

Tags: javascript, html

Just a quick one - If I were to have a link such as this (REST):

```
http://request.com/action.jsp?parameter={{insert}}
```

How would I add a little JavaScript to populate the param with text from a text field?

I will just have a small text box which I can enter something like 'TRUE' and when I hit a button it transforms the link to this:

```
http://request.com/action.jsp?paramter=TRUE
```

And executes the link.

What should I be using? I was thinking getElementByID will that work? Could I place all this in a  and use the following code?

```
document.getElementById("htmlDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("htmlText").value;
```

But how would I place the value from the text box into my link, make that value a variable? Any helps appreciated, trying to learn JavaScript and do a project at work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var link = document.getElementById('linkid'),
  textBox = document.getElementById('textInputId');
function setLinkParam() {
  link.href = 'http://request.com/action.jsp?parameter=' + textBox.value;
}
textBox.addEventListener('change', setLinkParam);
```